# My asynchronous actions in Redux/React is behaving strangely?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have your standard redux/react architecture using redux-promise to handle my react state only when the promise resolves. I am noticing some strange behaviours in respect to when I invoke a callback function inside my code. It seems that when I do not invoke a callback, then my `action.payload` is defined but when I do not invoke a callback function then `action.payload is defined`. Here are my relevant code/files:

**Register.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { registerUser } from '../actions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

class Register extends React.Component {

    onSubmit(values) {
        this.props.registerUser(values, function(res){
            console.log(res);
        });
    }

    render(){
    
    //html code with onsubmit func when form submits

      
}

function validate(values) {
    //redux form validation
}

export default reduxForm({
    validate,
    form: 'RegisterForm'
})(
    connect(null,{ registerUser })(Register)
);
```

**Reducer/index.js**

```js
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'
import PostReducer from './reducer-posts';
import AuthReducer from './reducer-auth';


const allReducers = combineReducers({
    posts: PostReducer,
    form: formReducer,
    auth: AuthReducer
});

export default allReducers
```

**reducer-auth.js**

```js
import { REGISTER_USER } from '../actions/index';

const INITIAL_STATE = { all: [], post: null };

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case REGISTER_USER:
            return { ...state, all: action.payload.data}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export const REGISTER_USER = 'REGISTER_USER';

const ROOT_URL = '/api';


export function registerUser(values, callback){
    const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/register`, values)
        .then(function (response) {
            callback(response);
        });

    return {
        type: REGISTER_USER,
        payload: request
    };

}
```

**Index.js**

```js
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
    promise
)(createStore);
```

how can I pass my return object to my reducer only when my promise has been resolved? It seems that when I have `.then()` in my action the reducer `action.payload` seems to be undefined but when i remove the `.then()` then `action.payload` becomes defined again??

Pretty confused with how this all works, can someone please clarify this for me? Thanks!

Comment: You need to condense all of this into a focused issue and section of code for us to look at, not your entire app

Comment: Thanks, I have removed code that does not need to be there. Only my relevant files/code.

Comment: I'm confused; why are you using redux-promise if you want to provide a callback?

Comment: i want it to be mapped to my state as well for use later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems that when I have .then() in my action the reducer
>   action.payload seems to be undefined but when i remove the .then()
>   then action.payload becomes defined again??

Whether you use then or not, the payload will be a Promise object from axios and not the resolved value of the axios request. So, this is not the right approach, which brings us to the next question.

> how can I pass my return object to my reducer only when my promise has
>   been resolved?

How do you pass anything to the reducer? Invoke an action. I would dispatch REGISTER_USER action after axios post request has been resolved.

```js
// actions.js
export function registerUser(values, dispatch){
  const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/register`, values)
    .then(function (response) {
        dispatch({type: REGISTER_USER, payload: response});
    });
}

// React Component
// some imports ...
class Register extends React.Component {
  onSubmit(values) {
    // this will send a post request and change the store
    this.props.registerUser(values);
  }

  render(){
    //html code with onsubmit func when form submits
  }

}

export default reduxForm({
  validate,
  form: 'RegisterForm'
})(
  // pass dispatch to registerUser
  connect(null, dispatch => ({ 
    registerUser: (values) => registerUser(values, dispatch) 
  }))(Register)
);
```

Alternatively, you can call the dispatch in the callback function that you pass into registerUser.